# SQLite XML SUBSTRING

Tags: c#, sql, xml, sqlite, substring

I have an NVARCHAR column in a SQLite database which stores XML data. I need to strip out an element of the XML in a SQLite query.

Column XMLDATA will contain XML similar to the following:-

```
<Inspection>
<Enquiry>
</Enquiry>
<Enqid>282256</Enqid>
<TargetDate>16/12/2011</TargetDate>
</Inspection>
```

I need to strip out the Enqid element of the XML document.

I could use substring but i need to find the index location of `<Enqid>` first.

I am using standard SQLite with no additional libraries.

Comment: i just found out SQLite does not support instr, substr_index, locate, charindex nor any other string position functions :((

Answer (score 1):

if it really **must** be in an SQLite query, i can't thing of anything better than manually listing all strings to be stripped out, like this:

```
replace(replace(xmldata,
'<Enquiry>
</Enquiry>
', ''),
'<second_element></second_element>', '')
as "stripped xmldata"
```

Comment: I think you got the wrong end of the stick, I need to keep the <Enquiry> tag not remove it as such. So i need to be able to select back just the <Enquiry> node and nothing else.

Comment: oh.. why is it empty in your example then? i have absolutelly no idea how to do *that* in SQLite :(

Comment: its Enqid i need not Enquiry.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using LIKE

select * from MyTable where XMLDATA LIKE '282256'

Comment: this seems to work but will only select back the entire XMLDATA column which is fine for what I want, but this would not work if i wanted to only retrieve part of the XML data in the XMLDATA column.